# Issue with Object to XML serialization in VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, complextype

I'm working in a Electronic Invoice system that works with XSD Schemas and XML, I have my vb classes from the XSD and I'm trying to serialize the XML but there is a complex type that I can seem to make it work.
So I have an Invoice class, with a detail class within and a CodeType class within the detail.
For an invoice with several lines, let's say 4, I'm supposed to have 4 different codes in the field CodoType, however each new code overwrites the last one so at the end I have 4 code fields with the exact same data, the code for the 4th item.
If I try to change it all 4 change to the same. 
Here' the Class Schema : [Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2w3W.png)

Here's my code:

```
  enter code here 
Dim Producto As New FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle
Dim items(20) As FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle
Dim Codigo0 As New CodigoType
Dim ProductoCodigos0(0) As CodigoType

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grdDetalle.Rows
            If row.Cells(0).Value = Nothing Then Exit For

            Producto.NumeroLinea = row.Index + 1
            Producto.Cantidad = row.Cells(4).Value
            Producto.UnidadMedida = 1
            Producto.Detalle = row.Cells(2).Value
            Producto.PrecioUnitario = FormatNumber(row.Cells(3).Value, 5)
            Producto.MontoTotal = Producto.PrecioUnitario * Producto.Cantidad
            Producto.MontoDescuento = 0.00000
            Producto.SubTotal = Producto.MontoTotal - Producto.MontoDescuento

            Codigo0 = New CodigoType
            Codigo0.Tipo = CodigoTypeTipo.Item01
            Codigo0.Codigo = row.Cells(1).Value
            ProductoCodigos0(0) = New CodigoType
            ProductoCodigos0(0) = Codigo0
            Producto.Codigo = ProductoCodigos0
            items(row.Index) = Producto
            Producto = New FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle

        Next row

        Factura.DetalleServicio = items
```

Thanks in advance for your help, I don't have much experience in XML so I apologize.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that even though you set a new item in the `ProductoCodigos0` array, the array itself remains the same. Meaning all of your class instances currently refer to the exact same array.

It is generally not very good practice to declare one-time variables outside a loop. If you would have declared all of them (except for `items`) inside the loop instead, you would never have had this problem.

Finally, instead of declaring `items` as a fixed size array, use a dynamic sized [**`List(Of T)`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) to better avoid `NullReferenceException`s, and `IndexOutOfRangeException`s when you have more than 21 items.

```vb
Dim items As New List(Of FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle)

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grdDetalle.Rows
    If row.Cells(0).Value = Nothing Then Exit For

    Dim Producto As New FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle
    Producto.NumeroLinea = row.Index + 1
    Producto.Cantidad = row.Cells(4).Value
    Producto.UnidadMedida = 1
    Producto.Detalle = row.Cells(2).Value
    Producto.PrecioUnitario = FormatNumber(row.Cells(3).Value, 5)
    Producto.MontoTotal = Producto.PrecioUnitario * Producto.Cantidad
    Producto.MontoDescuento = 0.00000
    Producto.SubTotal = Producto.MontoTotal - Producto.MontoDescuento

    Dim Codigo As New CodigoType
    Codigo.Tipo = CodigoTypeTipo.Item01
    Codigo.Codigo = row.Cells(1).Value
    Producto.Codigo = New CodigoType() {Codigo} 'Here we create the CodigoType array instead.

    items.Add(Producto)
Next

Factura.DetalleServicio = items.ToArray()
```

Comment: You fixed Vincent!!! Thank you very much for your help. You're awesome.